# Flexbox cascading items

Tags: html, css

I have 2 flex box containers. One of these is in row for and the other is in column for. What I am need to do is to have the items be in a cascading way. All items should have the same height and width but should be leveled in different positions.

Adjusting them margin of the container and items is not working.

HTML

```
 <div class="flex-review">
      <div class="review-card"></div>
      <div class="review-card"></div>
      <div class="review-card"></div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="main-card" id="higest-card"></div>
      <div class="main-card"></div>
      <div class="main-card"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS (firts part is for bottom cotainer with big items, second part is for top cotainer with small items)

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: space-between;

    

}

.main-card{
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #b8b5b5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-right: 40px;
   
    
}

.flex-review{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    
    

}

.review-card{
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #b8b5b5;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Currently looks like this:

[image: Current Layout]

[image: Goal Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

I set the divs to have relative positioning, and simply moved them using right/bottom.

```css
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: space-between;

    

}

.main-card{
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #b8b5b5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    
    position: relative;
}
.main-card:nth-child(1) {
  bottom: 100px;
}
.main-card:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 50px;
}

.flex-review{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.review-card{
    height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #b8b5b5;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    margin-top: 50px;
    
    position: relative;
}

.review-card:nth-child(1) {
  right: 100px;
}

.review-card:nth-child(2) {
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-review">
      <div class="review-card"></div>
      <div class="review-card"></div>
      <div class="review-card"></div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="main-card" id="higest-card"></div>
      <div class="main-card"></div>
      <div class="main-card"></div>
    </div>
```